# Eclipse CDT crash randomly under Windows 7 x64?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, windows-7-x64

I use the last JRE, Eclipse C++ package and Mingw. I can compile but Eclipse crash randomly in few minutes after it starts.

Log file :

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2011-03-11 20:08:04.087
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.core 4 0 2011-03-11 20:19:20.164
!MESSAGE Error while parsing /TD1_Seq/src/main.cpp.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at     org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.cpp.CPPASTTemplateId.accept(CPPASTTemplateId.java:162)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.cpp.CPPASTCompositeTypeSpecifier.accept(CPPASTCompositeTypeSpecifier.java:153)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.cpp.CPPASTSimpleDeclaration.accept(CPPASTSimpleDeclaration.java:89)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.cpp.CPPASTTemplateSpecialization.accept(CPPASTTemplateSpecialization.java:73)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.cpp.CPPASTNamespaceDefinition.accept(CPPASTNamespaceDefinition.java:116)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.ASTTranslationUnit.accept(ASTTranslationUnit.java:268)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.cpp.CPPASTTranslationUnit.resolveAmbiguities(CPPASTTranslationUnit.java:173)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.AbstractGNUSourceCodeParser.resolveAmbiguities(AbstractGNUSourceCodeParser.java:664)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.AbstractGNUSourceCodeParser.parse(AbstractGNUSourceCodeParser.java:651)
at org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.parser.AbstractCLikeLanguage.getASTTranslationUnit(AbstractCLikeLanguage.java:143)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.AbstractIndexerTask.createAST(AbstractIndexerTask.java:285)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.AbstractIndexerTask.createAST(AbstractIndexerTask.java:258)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.AbstractIndexerTask.parseFile(AbstractIndexerTask.java:754)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.AbstractIndexerTask.parseLinkage(AbstractIndexerTask.java:637)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.AbstractIndexerTask.runTask(AbstractIndexerTask.java:344)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.indexer.PDOMIndexerTask.run(PDOMIndexerTask.java:127)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.PDOMIndexerJob.run(PDOMIndexerJob.java:137)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I try to use option :
    `-vm "C:\Programs Files\java\bin\"`
but eclipse still crash and no error is report in log file.

log file : http://pastebin.com/zEgQjmPq

Answer (score 3):

This is this bug in the Java VM:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333227

There are workarounds:

- Add: -XX:-UseCompressedOops to your eclipse.ini
- Use an JVM older that 1.6.0_23
- Use a Java 7 VM
- Use a VM other Sun JVM

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this bug is very strange, I haven't change any parameters but my eclipse doesn't crash since 3 days so wtf :D

Answer (score 1):

On my machine (win 7 64, 1.6.0_24 JVM) eclipse CDT crashes every time when it tries to index a project. I've attempted to report a bug through help->report bug.., but CDT failed with some error again. I guess I will try netbeans)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use JVM update 22, it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed in JDK 1.6.0_26